# how to recognize a pdf programmatically(in java) whether it is normal(Searchable) or Scanned(image)?

Tags: java, pdf

I am Working on Pdfs to Excel conversion using docparser.
 But docparser is unable to process scanned pdfs properly. So **I need to seperate the scanned pdfs from normal pdfs** and only want to process normal pdfs through docparser(i.e API call).
**Is there exit some to way to identify the pdf type(Scanned or normal) programmatically** so that I could work further?
Please help if anyone knows how to tackle this problem.....

Comment: As far as I know, on the PDF level there is no difference between a "normal" and a "scanned" pdf.. So, you would have to do it heuristically. For example, if all pages include an image that is 90%+ of paper size, it's a pretty good bet that it's a scanned PDF..

Comment: Some scanned pdf have a scanner brand tag in their meta-data so you can identify them by it. But if the scanner doesn't add or modify the meta-data of the created pdf I guess it would be really hard to identify it.

Comment: Thanks for giving your answers guys ,But when I used Tabula - Pdf to Excel tool and uploaded a scanned pdf, it shows me a pop-up that "the uploaded file is scanned image, it may not give correct results....".So I think there surely exists some way to identify scanned Pdfs...

Comment: *"So I think there surely exists some way to identify scanned Pdfs"* - as @xs0 indicated you have to use heuristics. E.g. pages with only image content but no text...

Comment: We just gave you two ways to do that :-) Also, if you had OCR available, you could look at its scores as another signal..

Comment: First of all I was wondering why this question has been downvoted? The question is good and up to standards and please mention the reason for downvoting. Secondly, **@AmulMittal** please have a look at [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24184308/detect-if-a-pdf-is-created-from-a-scanned-document-using-ocr-pdfbox) answer. Also I recommend you to have a look at [**this**](https://docs.aspose.com/display/pdfnet/Find+whether+PDF+file+contains+images+or+text+only)

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I found a solution to my question.But not a standard one(I THINK SO). Thanks to the people who commented and provide some help.

Using **Pdfbox library** we can extract pages of scanned pdf and will **compare each page to the instance of an image object(PDImageXObject)**,if it comes true , the page will be count as  an image and we can count those images.**If** **images are equal to number of pages in pdf**. We will say it is a **scanned pdf**.

here is the **code**...

```
public static String testPdf(String filename) throws IOException
{
    String s = "";
    int g = 0;
    int gg = 0;
          PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(new File(filename));

          gg = doc.getNumberOfPages();
          for(PDPage page:doc.getPages())
          {
              PDResources resource = page.getResources();
              for(COSName xObjectName:resource.getXObjectNames())
                {
                    PDXObject xObject = resource.getXObject(xObjectName);
                    if (xObject instanceof PDImageXObject)
                    {
                        ((PDImageXObject) xObject).getImage();
                        g++;
                    }


          }

          }
          doc.close();
         if(g==gg)  // pdf pages if equal to the images
         {
             return "Scanned pdf";
         }
         else
         {
             return "Searchable pdf";
         }



}
```

Comment: can you please describe the problem you faced?